# SharePoint 2007 WSP deployment process, restarting SPTimerV3 service

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-deployment

I've got a WF feature which I've been deploying into my development/test environment fairly frequently, and as such have run into an issue where the assembly seems to be cached by the SharePoint Timer service (SPTimerV3), and then an out-of-date version is used after the workflow rehydrates following a Delay Activity.

To fix this, I've tried adding a "NET STOP SPTimerV3" and "NET START SPTimerV3" to my batch file after the STSADM commands to install the .WSP . It works to restart the timer service, and I no longer have the caching problem, however restarting the timer this way seems to kill my SP App Pools in IIS fairly regularly.

Has anyone found a good way to restart the timer in a WSP deployment batch file without adverse affects? Do I need to restart another dependent service, or restart the App Pools each time as well?

Comment: This is not exactly a programming question and I think you are more likely to get on answer if you post this question on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Well, it's relevant to the scripting in a batch file ;)   Honestly though thanks for the comment and I'd love to post it there, but currently cannot for corporate internet blocking issues... Hoping for the best here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to restart IIS as well. IISRESET /noforce should do the trick.

Comment: Works now with the basic pattern of: (1) Remove old WSP (2) Restart SPTimerV3 (3) Install new WSP (4) IISReset